# CSS mover imagen proporcionalmente a la pantalla independientemente del tamaño de ella

Tags: html, css, keyframes

```
.cuadrado2 {
background-color: blueviolet;
animation-name: cuadrado2;
animation-duration: 3s;
}   
@keyframes cuadrado2 {
from {transform: translatex(0px);}
to {transform: translatex(100%);}
}
```

Solo se mueve proporcionalmente al tamaño de la imagen, pero quiero que se mueva proporcionalmente al tamaño de la pantalla. saludos!

Answer (score 0):

TranslateX(100%) lo que esta haciendo es moverlo al 100% del ancho del elemento a la izquierda.

Cambia tu CSS por algo como position: absolute y a tu animacion cambiale las reglas de transform por left por ejemplo.

Igual esto depende de tus contenedores, porque position: absolute se ancla al contenedor superior que tenga un position relative, pero ya es un comienzo.

```css
.cuadro {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  animation-name: mover-fuera;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
}   

@keyframes mover-fuera{
  from {left:0;}
  to {left:100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="cuadro">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

QUISE DECIR QUE SI CAMBIABA LA UNIDAD DE MEDIDA A  "VW" ESTABA BIEN.
ESA ERA LA RESPUESTA Y QUE ME FUNCIONÓ.
SALUDOS!!!

Comment: Te recomiendo evitar usar mayúsculas, pues das la impresión de estar gritando.